# LSTM forecasting on multivariate time series

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, lstm, rnn

I'm new to RNNs and LSTM and would like some direction with a problem I have. I have a data set containing system metrics (like CPU utilization, disk operations, memory use) of an AWS EC2 instance with a total of 7 columns and around 8000 rows. Each row also has a timestamp with a 5 min interval between each row.

I want to build a LSTM model to forecast the performance for let's say the next hour based on my data. What would be the best approach for solving a problem like this? I know this can be done in many different ways but I would really appreciate some input how to go about this.

Comment: This is the result I got from following the tutorial on machine learning mastery. Any help interpreting the result? https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRGGx.jpg

Answer (score 1):

LSTM should be a good fit for this problem(as you mentioned in question).  It can identify patterns in sequence of data (For example : high memory usage is a leading indicator of  higher disk usage [due to higher usage of swap partition]).

[This](https://machinelearningmastery.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-lstms-keras/) is a tutorial for similar use-case.

Comment: Thank you, I will check the tutorial. Since every row in my dataset represent a 5 minute period, do you think it would be beneficial for my result to concatenate them into hours, or even days? If i keep it in the format I already have, should every row in the dataset represent one timestep? Sorry about all the questions, but I try to wrap my head around how to think when developing a LSTM model.

Comment: Yes, create a set of rows and create single training example. This example can represent 1 day (~300 rows) or 1 Hour . Try both to see which set is large enough for LSTM to learn repetitive patterns.

Comment: This is the result I got from following the tutorial on machine learning mastery. Any help interpreting the result?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRGGx.jpg